# How do I get rid of the ugly selection boxes around the desktop icons in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, icons

It used to be so that the icon shape itself was the selection area in 18.04 and you also had the option of not snapping the icons to grid, all of that seems to be gone now in 20.04. Could someone please help with that? I've included a snapshot of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpogk.jpg).